Heating foil working principle, how to fix it?
This is a heating foil from the side mirror of a car and is supposed to melt ice on the mirror on a cold day. It seems to be broken (significantly less power compared to the other mirror) but the reason is not obvious to me.

The resistance between the two terminals is 170 Ohms. At its nominal voltage of 12V it draws about 200mA, which is unexpectedly high when considering Ohm's law, but still not enough to properly heat the mirror glass.
One can see that the silver traces are dead ends rather than connecting the two terminals, so it must be assumed that the foil itself is somehow conductive? There are no traces visible on the backside.
Questions:

What is the working principle of that foil?
How to find the reason for the high resistance / how to fix it?

What I tried:

Inspect traces for cracks or other damage. Nothing.
Slightly increase voltage to ~16V. Current raises linear.
Carefully bend the foil while observing the measured resistance. No changes.
Measure resistance between a terminal and its connected "silver" trace: Open loop. Might be due to an insulating film on the trace that I did not succeed to scratch away.
Change temperature down to 0°C / 32°F because I found that these foils may have a PTC characteristic. Measured resistance remains unchanged.


I'd love to know the resistance of the other mirror heater, between the two connection terminals.


What is the working principle of that foil?

Two separated silver traces are low-resistance paths to two separate terminals. Black resistive (carbon?) print is resistive heater material.

How to find the reason for the high resistance / how to fix it?

If a silver trace is broken, silver epoxy over-paint is the likely fix.

Measure resistance between a terminal and its connected "silver"
trace: Open loop. Might be due to an insulating film on the trace that
I did not succeed to scratch away.

That doesn't make sense, and your suspicion of poor connection is well-founded. The silver traces connected to one terminal should measure near-zero ohms from any point along that trace back to its terminal. A thin over-all coating of glue appears to be an insulating barrier to an ohmmeter probe. Poking through the glue should be done gently, else you risk damaging the silver trace. Am unsure if a solvent might wash away the glue (I'd hesitate trying this).
The weak-link on those silver traces is often where it attaches to its terminal...the terminal gets much stress causing intermittent connection to the silver trace.
I have marked out in yellow one of the two silver traces. You should measure very low resistance between any two points along that yellow trace. Attach one end of your ohmmeter to its terminal, and probe with the other ohmmeter lead to various points along that yellow trace -should be near-zero ohms.
Then attach one ohmmeter probe to the other (un-coloured) terminal. Probe along the un-coloured silver trace...should be near-zero ohms anywhere probed.
I have also outlined lightly in red a stress mark where this plate was attached to the mirror mount. Probing silver traces in this vicinity should be done carefully.

I had no idea that's how they were made.  I assumed it was just some standard off-the-shelf (or custom built) strip heaters wired in parallel.
